# What is the sum $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{r}{4r^4+1}$ equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Problem : 
If $$T_r =\frac{r}{4r^4+1}$$ then the value of $$\sum^{\infty}_{r=1} T_r$$ is ?

How to start such problem I am not getting any clue on this please suggest thanks .

Comment: Start by factoring $4r^4+1$. Then do a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Note that \begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}T_r &=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{r}{4r^4+1}\\
&=\frac14\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2r^2-2r+1}-\frac{1}{2r^2+2r+1}\right)\\
&=\frac14\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2r^2-2r+1}-\frac{1}{2(r+1)^2-2(r+1)+1}\right).\\
\end{align}

From this point, I am sure you can carry on the sum using telescoping series.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$4r^4+1=(2r^2+1+2r)\cdot(2r^2+1-2r)$$